# Ubuntu log in/initialization mode

Tags: gui, mode

in what log in/initialization mode should ubuntu be for the GUI to boot automatically?

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 15.04 and later uses runlevel 5 (called as `graphical.target`) as its default graphical target. [Earlier versions](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#runlevels) before 15.04 used the runlevel 2 as its default graphical mode.

```
   Runlevels in Ubuntu 15.04+
   ┌─────────┬───────────────────┐
   │Runlevel │ Target            │
   ├─────────┼───────────────────┤
   │0        │ poweroff          │
   ├─────────┼───────────────────┤
   │1        │ rescue mode       │
   ├─────────┼───────────────────┤
   │2, 3, 4  │ multi-user mode   │
   ├─────────┼───────────────────┤
   │5        │ graphical mode    │
   ├─────────┼───────────────────┤
   │6        │ reboot            │
   └─────────┴───────────────────┘
```

You can see the default runlevel/target in 15.04+ by:

```
systemctl get-default
```

If the output of the above command is not `graphical.target`, you can set it by:

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the desktop version of Ubuntu, a graphical user interface should be started by default. If you installed Ubuntu server, you would have to install various packages to get a graphical user interface. Perhaps the easiest would be to install the Ubuntu desktop meta-package:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

If you have a Ubuntu desktop installation, and no graphical user interface is started. You have to make sure you have X (type `start x` from a shell for example), a display manager (e.g. `lightdm`) and a window manager of some kind (e.g. `compiz`).